# python signal send data to recipient in frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals

Python 2.7 Program 'A' sends SIGUSR1 to program 'B'.
Python 2.7 Program 'B' opens a tcp/ip socket and sends some info to Program 'A'
This works fine.

At the moment the port for program 'B'' to use for its socket is hard coded in its sigusr1 handler.

I would like for program 'A' to be able to tell program 'B' what port to use.

When the signal arrives at program 'B' it delivers a frame object.

```
def usr1_handler(self, signum, frame):
    HOST, PORT = 'localhost', 11001
```

Is there a way for me to embed the requested IP port within the frame object so that program 'B' can retrieve the port in its sigusr1 handler?

Answer (score 1):

When signal is received in program B, Python execution is interrupted and the frame in the signal handler corresponds to the current stack frame **in program B**. It is purely on the "client" side: there is no way to pass data from the signal emitter program to the receiver.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I had been confused about the content of the frame but you've helped me to understand.  I'll have to figure out some other way to do what I want...

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? It's not so clear from your question.

Comment: A program creates a tcp server that listens on some port.  I would like to be able to inform prospective client tasks of the port to use for communication of data when the client receives a SIGUSR1

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean B does not know the port but wanna receive the port from A?
I suggest B sniff the network flow from A,then retrieve the port from frames.Well,it takes more time